# How to start and stop a python program in C++?

Tags: python, c++, batch-file

I am trying start another program in C++(windows).
The C++ needs to execute `starter.bat --debug --verbose`, in the `starter.bat`, it runs `%SF_HOME%\files\program-start.pyc %*`. After the program runs, how could I stop the `program-start.pyc` in C++? How to send `control+c` to it ? I cannot find it by using `taskList` in windows command line.

```
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO processInfo;

processInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
processInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
processInfo.hwnd = NULL;
processInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
processInfo.lpFile = L"C:\\Users\\Li\\ddddp\\bin\\scripts\\dddpstart.pyc";
processInfo.lpParameters = L"--device-type  --device-serial yyyyy --device-model TEST --debug --verbose";
processInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
processInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
processInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&processInfo);

TerminateProcess(processInfo.hProcess, 1);
```

Then a console pops up but it doesn't stop at the end of the code.

Comment: "How to start and stop a python program in C++?" - The same way you start/stop any other program. Python is irrelevant here.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: I post the code I tried, see the updates. @Robert